# How to consume RESTful web services in a custom module?

Tags: 7, hooks, webforms, services

I have an API which I would like to consume to do specific actions on my Drupal 7 website after getting data from the user via a webform form. I plan to write my own custom module to do that but don't know how where I should start from.

Is there any hook that could help me add supplementary action after getting data from my webform ? How am I supposed to proceed to consume my web services ? Any code snippet, advice, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module [RESTClient](https://www.drupal.org/project/restclient) is for this purpose.

It provides 4 APIs:

- `restclient_get()`
- `restclient_post()`
- `restclient_put()`
- `restclient_delete()`

Comment: I successfully tested [RestClient] (https://www.drupal.org/project/restclient) with key/value pairs sent for the query as plain text. However, I couldn't consume my RestFul APIs with which is based on XML queries. So my question now is how to use RestClient module to consume Restful API using XML queries ?

Comment: I guess your problem is how to create xml content with PHP, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. And how to use my XML with RestClient.

Comment: Just put `array('body' => $xml_str)` as the second arguments in the mentioned APIs. You are better to create a new question about constructing xml content with PHP in StackOverflow.

Comment: Where can we find some documentation about Restclient module? I cant find any on the module page.

Comment: @SinanErdem It's documentation is suck. I read its code to find these APIs.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy Ko, do you know the format or parameters those methods get?

Comment: @SinanErdem Their code comment is pretty well. You can read it from http://cgit.drupalcode.org/restclient/tree/restclient.module

Answer (score 0):

Most would agree here that there is no need to re-invent the wheel. There are already at least 4 wheels here that can be used. The Services module, which also has support for the Webform module (through another contributed module), is the most popular module for this job:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/services
- https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_service

The other big players would be the [RESTful](https://www.drupal.org/project/restful) module, [restws](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws) and as Jimmy Ko mentioned, [RESTClient](https://www.drupal.org/project/restclient). Although I don't personally have experience with these last 3, all 4 will have their pros/cons. Each should have sufficient documentation and code examples in the wild to get you started.

Comment: Most modules you listed here is to create restful service but not to consume restful APIs.

Answer (score 0):

[Web Service Clients](https://www.drupal.org/project/clients) was the only module I could get to work.

You create a connection via UI. Then you can use the API and make your requests from code.

Example API usage:

```
// 'my_connection' is the machine name of the connection.
$result = clients_connection_call('my_connection', 'method.name', $param1, $param2, $param_etc);
```